Extract Unique Values from a Power BI JSON in Power Automate
I have the following JSON that comes from PowerBI (via the Power Automate button function)
[
  {
    "entity": {
      "Power BI values": [
        {
          "G-DATEMO": 4,
          "G-DATEQU": 2,
          "G-DATEYR": 2024,
          "G-PRODUCT": "Biscuit",
          "G-BAKERY": "West",
          "Year Quarter Name": "2024 Q2"
        },
        {
          "G-DATEMO": 4,
          "G-DATEQU": 2,
          "G-DATEYR": 2024,
          "G-PRODUCT": "Bun",
          "G-BAKERY": "West",
          "Year Quarter Name": "2024 Q2"
        },
        {
          "G-DATEMO": 4,
          "G-DATEQU": 2,
          "G-DATEYR": 2024,
          "G-PRODUCT": "Bun",
          "G-BAKERY": "South",
          "Year Quarter Name": "2024 Q2"
        },
      ]
    }
  }
]


I want to extract only the UNIQUE items for G-PRODUCT and G-BAKERY listed if its possible in separate arrays
I have tried applying a "apply to each" in side another "apply to each" but just end up with the array being full of 'Apply_to_each_2"
Need to achieve this inside of Power Automate

what is your expected output?

Hi,
Something like:
{
West,
South
}
and
{
Biscuit,
Bun
}

I saved your data into an array variable:

The next step is to create a parse json action which will describe the structure of your json that was provided. In the content, I put the sample data array that I created. The schema should look like this:

{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "entity": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "Power BI values": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "G-DATEMO": {
                                    "type": "integer"
                                },
                                "G-DATEQU": {
                                    "type": "integer"
                                },
                                "G-DATEYR": {
                                    "type": "integer"
                                },
                                "G-PRODUCT": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "G-BAKERY": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "Year Quarter Name": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Next, you need to create two select actions to extract the correct values for each item. it should automatically create the loop for you if you select the correct inputs:

Instead of initializing the two arrays at the beginning, do it after the loop, and use the output from the selects as the initial values for your arrays.

The last step is to remove the duplicates from each array. Create a compose action for each array, and use the following expression:


Thank you, but i am still unable to get this to work.
Where you have "For Each 1" and soon as i add the select in and put in the "entity.power bi values" it creates another "For Each". How did you not create one above?
The end result is just:
[
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, (and so on)
]
Is the no append to the variables created because i not drunk enough coffee and dont see how you put these into the variables.

yes so don't put a for each action yourself. Add a select action first, and put the necessary parameters. It will automatically wrap it in a for each loop

Not sure what I am doing wrong then. Directly after the JSON i choose "select". As soon as I select "Power BI Items" (I have a choice of item, entity, Body, Power BI Values) it gives me the first "For Each" loop.
As soon as i select "G-Bakery" (I have to switch to map to text mode to do this) it immediately puts me into another "For Each"
Thus i keep coming out with "null, null, null"
What part am I doing wrong?

In addition, directly after the For-each (the first one), if i do a compose and G-Bakery then the variable is just empty

I see what you mean, I forgot a step. let me update my answer for you

I updated it for you

thank you for sticking with this.
There is no way to reference the "select" inside the loop. The only way to get hold of it so to speak is to create a compose inside of the loop, put the output of the select in there and then copy it out to the variable below deleting the compose.
The RAW input though into the Initialize variable is empty though. The Select is now doing its job (who know it would be case sensitive!) but I can't get it out of the loop.
You cant take the output of the loop either into the Array as it errors with a Foreach scope of action

you don't need to reference the select inside the loop. You use the output of the select to initialize your arrays after the loop

You cant reference easily the output of the select outside of the loop.
I have eventually got this to work, to others whom come after me:

Initialize variable before loop
When adding the select, choose "Power BI Values" and then for Map, add it using the expression ability (in the above example, item()?['G-Bakery]). This will stop Automate triggering another loop addition
In the for each loop, select "Set Variable" and select the output of the select
Outside of the loop, do the compose and union

Then this works.
Thankk you @IBEMeltin for helping getting to this part!

no problem, if my answers were helpful you can upvote and select my answer :)
